# Django Admin Static Files on Apache

Tags: django, apache

There are quite a few posts on here regarding the same subject, I've tried as many as I thought applicable. Yet, I still have this error. Everything is being served fine for a django site I've built except the static files for admin.

Versions: Django 1.6, Apache 2.4.7, Ubuntu 14.04

Ok - I have ran manage.py collectstatic and here is the static folder:

```
/srv/bahai-site/bahai-site/soul/static
```

This contains four folders: 1) admin/ 2) bootstrap/ 3) core/ and 4) flags/

Within these folders, I can see all expected static files and that they contain the code I'd expect.

When looking at a static file on the site itself, something like /static/core/css/desktop_992.css loads correctly while /static/admin/css/base.css throws a 404.

Apache directives in http.conf:

```
Alias /static/ /srv/bahai-site/bahai-site/soul/static/

<Directory /srv/bahai-site/bahai-site/soul/static/>
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/bahai-site/soul/soul/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /srv/bahai-site/soul/soul:/srv/envelope/bahai-site/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<Directory /srv/bahai-site/soul/soul>
<Files wsgi.py>
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Side question: notice the WSGIScriptAlias and WSGIPythonPath only contains one "bahai-site/" directory level, instead of the two that actually exist after "/srv/". Why is the site running fine? Shouldn't that be causing a problem?

Anyway, what am I doing wrong here? How do I get these admin static files up and running?

Comment: sounds like django doesn't have permission to access those directories.  did you run the sudo command when you ran collectstatic?

Comment: I tried running the command with sudo and no change. The admin files were already collected into the static folder and this gave me the 0 static files copied, nnn files unmodified message

Answer (score 0):

as far as the pythonpath is concerned I personally don't include that in my apache virtual host config file and it works.  Maybe that's not needed?  Honestly I'm not all that well versed in server installations.  It defintely seems like a permission issue.

I would run collectstatic using sudo, then I would also make sure the static folder has www-data group permission which is the permission apache uses out of the box.

If you need help setting permissions on a folder in Ubuntu check out this link here.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/244406/how-do-i-give-www-data-user-to-a-folder-in-my-home-folder

Comment: I'm not sure about the python path, I just followed the instruction on the djangoproject site: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Anyway, sudo colletstatic didn't help and I have granted the appropriate permissions on a parent directory

Comment: the issue may be in your settings.py file than.  do you have satic_url and media_url set?

Comment: I have static files as this:                                 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'       I"m not currently using any media in the project so I don't have that set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had updated two different configuration files for Apache with competing directives.

Note to Other Beginners:

Directives (i.e. things like ...) can be placed in any file in the apache2 root -- in my case that was any file within /etc/apache2/. (Question to advanced users: is this only for Ubuntu? Or pretty much any Linux/Unix?) This will confuse you because, if you solve a problem using information from multiple online posts/documents, you'll likely have a smorgasbord of various people's Apache configuration preferences/styles. Hence my problem.

As a beginner, you're probably expecting to see some kind of single location you can put your configurations/customizations (in this case directives) into. That's not the case on Apache. You can put any of these anywhere. This is probably good once you advance your knowledge of Apache but it sucks when you're starting out.

My fix here was to go through all the files I touched in the /etc/apache2/ folder and consolidate any rules into one place. This lead to me removing duplicate/conflicting rules, which solved the problem.

Now I think I need to talk to a therapist....